# Regular expression to negate two either-or words

Tags: regex

I have a long list that of which a snippet looks something like this:

```
X1000ABC
X1100ABC
X2000ABC
X2200ABC
X3000ABC
X3300ABC
```

Could someone explain how I can go about matching *all* of the strings *except* `X1000ABC` and `X2000ABC`?

My problem is that I have a long (and potentially growing) list of codes that differ only in the 4 digit numbers. Two of those codes (I know which two) out of that list need to be excluded.

I tried using negative lookahead, but... I probably got the syntax wrong since I can't seem to get "or" to work with it. Or... I just don't understand lookahead.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you need this for. But it might be more practicable to check each line "by hand", i.e. without regexp. Just compare against `X1000ABC` and `X2000ABC`. If it matches, discard these lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
^(?!X1000ABC$)(?!X2000ABC$)X[0-9]{4}ABC$
```

[See it on Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/E4dDnQZInV)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it in the flavor of regex supported by JavaScript:

```
(?!X[12]000ABC)X[0-9]{4}ABC
```

This uses a character class inside the lookahead. Add `^` and `$` anchors at the beginning and end (including `$` inside the lookahead) if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
X(?![12]000)\d{4}ABC
```

tested in python

```
>>> x
'X1000ABC\nX1100ABC\nX2000ABC\nX2200ABC\nX3000ABC\nX3300ABC'
>>> re.findall("X(?![12]000)\d{4}ABC",x)
['X1100ABC', 'X2200ABC', 'X3000ABC', 'X3300ABC']
```